# Obtener fechas de columnas repetidas MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Buenas tardes comunidad de programadores,

Mi consulta viene relacionada a una query de mysql (MariaDB).

Estoy intentando obtener 6 variables de valores repetidos de una tabla. Latitude, Longitude y fecha/hora del primer valor repetido y el ultimo. Ej:

Con esta query obtengo la latitud y longitud repetida en la tabla:

```
select  t1.id,
    t1.latitude,
    t1.longitude,
    t1.reg_date,
    t1.reg_time
    from techcoy t1
    inner join ( select     latitude,
                longitude 
            from techcoy
            group by latitude,
                longitude 
            having count(1) > 1
    ) t2
    on t1.latitude = t2.latitude
    and t1.longitude = t2.longitude;
```

Quedaria algo asi:
Tabla: techcoy

| id | fecha | hora | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-03 | 17:40:31 | -11.1111111 | 11.1111111 |
| 2 | 2021-02-03 | 17:40:32 | -11.1111111 | 11.1111111 |
| 3 | 2021-02-03 | 17:40:33 | -11.1111111 | 11.1111111 |
| 4 | 2021-02-03 | 17:40:34 | -11.1111111 | 11.1111111 |

*Esta consulta me devuelve todos los valores repetidos de latitud y longitud.*

Necesito obtener la hora 17:40:31 (que es el punto de inicio de la repeticion) tambien 17:40:34 (que es la ultima hora repetida del evento).

Todo esto junto a la Latitude y Longitude repetidas.

(Tambien estoy intentando usar `SELECT * FROM techcoy WHERE reg_date >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;`para filtrar por dias, pero me toma como 2 querys distintas y no filtra los datos en 1 consulta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues, ya hiciste todo el trabajo.. solo te falta el moño..

Si la consulta que mostras saca casi lo que vos queres, solo te falta agrupar, obtener maximo y minimo y listo!

Digamos que te falta esto:

```
Select t1.latitude,
    t1.longitude,
    t1.reg_date,
    Max(t1.reg_time) as maximo,
    Min(t1.reg_time) as minimo
from
    (aca va toda la consulta que tenes hasta ahora) t1
group by    t1.latitude,
    t1.longitude,
    t1.reg_date;
```

Comment: Estoy recien comenzando en el desarrollo web. Te agradezco un millon!

Comment: Esto no es desarrollo web. Esto es sql.. deberias estudiar eso tambien

Comment: Se que es una base de datos, bajale un poco a tu pedal.

Comment: Jajajaja... es que como dijiste que recien empezabas con desarrollo web, tenia miedo que estuviers confuso de que es cada cosa... mejor asi :)...